# Find all vertices that are part of a 4 Cycle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find all vertices in an undirected graph that are part of a $k$ cycle. Where $k$ is fixed and $k > 3$. For the case of $k = 3$ we can look at the non-zero elements of the main diagonal of $A^3$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph. However, this approach does not translate easily to larger $k$'s

1. Is there a similar 'trick' for longer cycles?
2. If not, are there more efficient algorithms than depth first search for this problem?

Comment: You can find from each vertex the set of vertices at a distance of 2 via DFS. Duplicates will indicate 4-cycles. This should be more efficient than a depth 4 search. The generalization probably have no efficient algorithms, if $k=n$, this is equivalent to the Hamiltonian Cycle Problem, which is $NP$-complete.